# Installing Pillow on Python (Ubuntu14.04) on Codeanywhere

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I am currently trying hard to install Pillow on my codeanywhere python container using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

And currently it's not working and as a novice coder I've got no idea why.

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libjpeg8-dev is already the newest version.
libjpeg8-dev set to manually installed.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libdrm-nouveau2 libelf1 libfontconfig1
  libfontconfig1-dev libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libice-dev libice6 libjbig-dev
  libjbig0 liblcms2-2 libllvm3.4 liblzma-dev libpng12-dev
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libsm6 libtcl8.6 libtiff5 libtiffxx5
  libtk8.6 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libutempter0 libwebp5 libwebpdemux1 libwebpmux1
  libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb1 libxau-dev libxau6
  libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0
  libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb1 libxcb1-dev libxcomposite1 libxdamage1
  libxdmcp-dev libxdmcp6 libxext-dev libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft-dev libxft2
  libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2 libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2
  libxrender-dev libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxss-dev libxss1 libxt-dev libxt6
  libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 pkg-config sgml-base
  shared-mime-info tcl8.6 tk8.6 x11-common x11-utils x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-render-dev
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-xext-dev xbitmaps xml-core
  xorg-sgml-doctools xterm xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  libglide3 libice-doc liblcms2-utils liblzma-doc libsm-doc libxcb-doc
  libxext-doc libxt-doc tix python-tk-dbg sgml-base-doc tcl-tclreadline
  tcl8.6-doc tk8.6-doc mesa-utils debhelper xfonts-cyrillic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libdrm-nouveau2 libelf1 libfontconfig1
  libfontconfig1-dev libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libice-dev
  libice6 libjbig-dev libjbig0 liblcms2-2 liblcms2-dev libllvm3.4 liblzma-dev
  libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libsm6 libtcl8.6 libtiff5
  libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5 libtk8.6 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libutempter0 libwebp-dev
  libwebp5 libwebpdemux1 libwebpmux1 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-dev
  libx11-doc libx11-xcb1 libxau-dev libxau6 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0
  libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb1
  libxcb1-dev libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp-dev libxdmcp6 libxext-dev
  libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft-dev libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2 libxmu6
  libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender-dev libxrender1 libxshmfence1
  libxss-dev libxss1 libxt-dev libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1
  pkg-config python-tk sgml-base shared-mime-info tcl8.6 tcl8.6-dev tk8.6
  tk8.6-dev x11-common x11-utils x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  xbitmaps xml-core xorg-sgml-doctools xterm xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 102 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Need to get 7879 kB/33.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 137 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libelf1 amd64 0.158-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main fontconfig-config all 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libelf1 amd64 0.158-0ubuntu5.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libfreetype6 amd64 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libxml2 amd64 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libfontconfig1 amd64 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgl1-mesa-dri amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libglapi-mesa amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgl1-mesa-glx amd64 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libtiff5 amd64 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libtiff5 amd64 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libfreetype6-dev amd64 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libtiffxx5 amd64 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libfontconfig1-dev amd64 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libtiff5-dev amd64 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libtiff5-dev amd64 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/elfutils/libelf1_0.158-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/fontconfig-config_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/libfontconfig1_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libglapi-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiffxx5_4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6-dev_2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/libfontconfig1-dev_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5-dev_4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the error messages in the output, `apt-get` is trying tor retrieve package versions that are not available in the repository anymore. You have to update the package index: `sudo apt-get update`. Then run `sudo apt-get install ...` again.